# What physical forces allows for electromagnetic induction

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electric-circuits, magnetic-fields, induction

In electromagnetic induction, what force is actually doing the work? what physical force actually drives the electrons around the circuit?

Let's say we have a coil and an increasing magnetic field through the loop. The electrons start to flow by faraday's law. Is there a very real electric field that is induced around the wire which does the work? because magnetic fields can most certainly not do work.

Also, why do the charges even start moving in the first place? At each instant in time, there is some instantaneous value for the magnetic field. The magnetic field cannot cause the electrons to start moving because it doesn't affect stationary charges

Comment: Feel free to view my non-mathematic explanation (not description) of electromagnetic induction in my answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/166941/induction-and-electromagnetic-fields/368766#368766

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Induction and electromagnetic fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/166941/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider [Faraday's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday's_law_of_induction), which states that

$$
\nabla \times \textbf{E} = -\frac{\partial \textbf{B}}{\partial t}.
$$

We can interpret this as follows: whenever we are generating a magnetic field that changes with time, there is an associated electric field, and *vice-versa*. An equivalent interpretation is that a changing magnetic field causes a spatially varying electric field, but this view is mathematically equivalent to the first. The only important point is that whenever there is a changing magnetic field, an electric field will be present as well.

Let's now consider the situation where there is a coil (with no current flowing through it) and a changing magnetic field (perpendicular to cross sections of the coil) due to some external source. As I mentioned, because there is a changing $\textbf{B}$ field, there *must* also be an $\textbf{E}$ field as well (whether or not the changing magnetic field is causing the electric field is a matter of semantics, as I mentioned). It is this electric field which causes the current to begin flowing.

However, due to the magnetic field, there will also be an additional force on the electrons once they start moving. If we consider individual electrons, there will be a drift force from the magnetic field that changes the direction of their velocity. This is due to the $\textbf{v} \times \textbf{B}$ component of the [Lorentz force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force).

To summarize:

1. Changing magnetic field implies that there is an associated electric field.
2. The electric field causes a current to flow in the wire.
3. The magnetic field produces a drift force on the charges in the current.

Answer (score 0):

**In electromagnetic induction, what force is actually doing the work?**

For a wire that isn't moving, it is the electric force that does the work.

**What physical force actually drives the electrons around the circuit?**

If there the circuit is moving, the magnetic force can also contribute to the EMF, the work comes from the $\vec B$ field diverting the electrons which allows the electric field of the protons pulling it back.  When the circuit is staying still, it is 100% entirely the electric force doing the work.

**Let's say we have a coil and an increasing magnetic field through the loop. The electrons start to flow by faraday's law. Is there a very real electric field that is induced around the wire which does the work?**

The electrons start to flow because of the electric field (the protons are prevented from moving the opposite direction because of atomic and molecular forces, the lattice merely gets strained overall instead of a flow of protons).  The electric field is very real.

**Also, why do the charges even start moving in the first place?**

They were already moving because of thermal motion, but there was no average motion, the nonzero average motion develops in the first place because of the electric field.

**At each instant in time, there is some instantaneous value for the magnetic field.**

Sure, but there is also a curl of $\vec E$, and the curl of $\vec E$ is related to the change in $\vec B$, so if there is an expanding region where $\vec B$ changes, there is also an expanding region where there is a nonzero curl of $\vec E$.

**The magnetic field cannot cause the electrons to start moving because it doesn't affect stationary charges**

When there is zero average net velocity for the electrons, then the $\vec B$ field does zero average net force (if the $\vec B$ field changes a great deal over a region small enough where you don't get good averages this might fail but there are likely electric fields in those regions, so the magnetic effects are small unless the charges are moving quite fast).  But it isn't the $\vec B$ field itself, but only the changing $\vec B$ field that is related to the circulating electric field.  Back when and where the $\vec B$ field changed, the electric field was circulating.  And since then there was an expanding sphere where the $\vec B$ field changed and everywhere that the changing $\vec B$ field went, the circulating electric field did more than follow, it was there at the exact same time.  So back when the $\vec B$ field changed somewhere, there had to be a circulating electric field, and they propagated together ever since.  The circulating electric field arrives at the same time as the change in $\vec B$ field arrives.

Once a current starts to flow, there is a net velocity and so a net magnetic force is possible, this separates the mobile electrons from the stationary protons, and the resulting electric fields from the charge separation can do work.