# Mutual induction, how long does it last?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I understand the process of mutual induction and why it occurs, but i have a doubt. Imagine we have two circular coils. One is connected to a fem generator and the other isn't. Here it's what i've understood. If i close the loop of the firs due to a phenomenon of self induction the current for a specific amount of time is not constant but it increases until the loop reaches the a stationarity. So the flux of the magnetic field in the second coil changes in THAT amount of time and it produces an inducted fem, hence a current.
About the second loop, is there a self induction? If yes, there will be an alteration of the flux in the first loop and so the process of mutual induction will never finish! I don't understand how long there is a current in the second loop and why it doesn't affect the first circuit. I hope i've been clear.
Thank for your answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Induction and electromagnetic fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/166941/induction-and-electromagnetic-fields)

Comment: What is "fem generator"? What is "a stationarity"? Why would current in a loop increase after you connect its terminals? Is there some variable magnetic field?